# EF Code-first SetInitializer doesn't re-create database in NUnit TextFixture setup

Tags: entity-framework, nunit, code-first

I call the following for my EF code-first model at the beginning of my NUnit Text Fixture.

```
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
       DbDatabase.SetInitializer(
                    new MyDbInitialiser());
...

    }
```

`MyDbInitialiser` inherits from `DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDatabaseContext>`

Why does the NUnit test fixture run the initializer only once even when I re-run the whole fixture of tests?

If I close the NUnit runner and re-run the tests, the database does drop and get re-created.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `[Setup]` attribute instead. Any method marked with this attribute will be called before each `[Test]`.

http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setup&r=2.2.10

Comment: Hi, no I want it to re-create the database after each re-run of all my tests, not after each individual test.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with EF, but is there a method that you could call in a TestFixtureTearDown to clean up after running the tests?  This might guarantee that when you run the tests a second time it will run all of the setup again (as opposed to keeping something in cache)

Answer (score 0):

The class Database has methods like Delete, Create, Initialize. I think you can call them yourself to achieve what you're after.